# Circleci Rspec command takes more than 10 mintues TIMEOUT error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, circleci

Guys I am stuck at Timeout error on circleci. 
Test cases are running fine on localhost but on circleci I get following error.

> command bundle exec rspec took more than 10 minutes since last output

I have tried many changes but still my build fails due to TIMEOUT error.
I have also tried adding --format progress in bundle exec rspec command. but still same issue.

Here are my Configs for all file.

```
machine:
  environment:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: key
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: secret
    AWS_REGION: us-east-1
    TEST_CLUSTER_COMMAND: elasticsearch-1.5.2/bin/elasticsearch
    TEST_CLUSTER_LOGS: /tmp
    TEST_CLUSTER_NODES: 1
    HOST: localhost:3000
    QR_DOMAIN: test.bsqr1.com
  ruby:
    version: 2.3.1
  hosts:
    test.bsqr1.com: 127.0.0.1
dependencies:
  bundler:
    without: [development]
  cache_directories:
    - elasticsearch-1.5.2
  post:
    - if [[ ! -e elasticsearch-1.5.2 ]]; then wget https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-1.5.2.tar.gz && tar -xvf elasticsearch-1.5.2.tar.gz; fi
test:
  override:
    - bundle exec rspec:
      parallel: true
```

**Test.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure static file server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.serve_static_files = true
  config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=3600'

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Randomize the order test cases are executed.
  config.active_support.test_order = :random

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost', port: 3000}

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test
  config.react.variant = :development
  #sdm
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.logger = Logger.new $stdout
  config.assets.compress = true # Compress precompiled assets
  config.assets.compile = false # Refuse to compile assets on-the-fly
  config.assets.digest = true   # Add a cache-busting extension to asset filenames
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "file://#{::Rails.root}/public"
  #sdm end
end
```

Comment: Hi, I don't see the RAILS_ENV in the CI settings (machine -> environment). Could you set `RAILS_ENV: test`? Or some other env you need to run it within.

Comment: Hi..!! I just fixed the issue. The problem was in asset compilation. In test env, some stylesheets were not property compiling

Answer (score 0):

```
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.assets.logger = Logger.new $stdout
  config.assets.compress = true # Compress precompiled assets
  config.assets.compile = true # Refuse to compile assets on-the-fly
  config.assets.digest = true   # Add a cache-busting extension to asset filenames
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "file://#{::Rails.root}/public"
```

I added this in my test.rb file there were also some style sheets issue.